# How to shorten Class names on creating jar

Tags: java

i am creating jar, which has few packages and classes. But when i try to extract jar by zip utility it breakdown and give error file name is too long, Is it possible to shorten class names while creating jar, So i don't need to rename class names Manually?

Comment: If you rename classes you break things.  Presumably what you want to do is to reduce the total path length?  I think this is a matter of setting the current working directory correctly, but I haven't created a JAR in a couple of years.

Comment: You could try searching for obfuscator. They rename classes, but for the purpose of making your classes harder to reverse engineer. I bet some of them will rename them as "class1", "class2". Alternatively, unpack not from root package but from your root package (v.g. `com.twid.myapp`)

Comment: Find a not-broken unzip program.

Comment: What zip utility are you using?

Comment: Is the problem in the zip utility, or Windows?  I know (at least older versions of) Windows chokes on long path names, so if the folder you're extracting to is already nested deep, you might be hitting this. Try extracting the jar file to somewhere near the root of the drive, like to `C:/temp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already posted: Extract it to root folder (/) in unix or C:/ in windows

That should work because the problem is likely to be that the name (including the path being extracted to) is too long, not the names in the jar themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Extract it to root folder (/) in unix or C:/ in windows

Comment: How does that answer the question? He can't extract it, and you suggest him to extract it.

Comment: @JBNizet: I think he's getting at what I just put in my comment on the question.  Windows chokes on long path names, so extracting to the root will give you the best chance of not hitting the path length limit.

Comment: Totally agree with Mark. Shortening the class names/packages during unzipping can make it useless if it is going to be connected to an IDE where there are compiled classes. Also, if the Jar contains lot of classes, it is becomes increasingly difficult to see a desired class (as the names have changed). Please let me know if this needs any more clarity.